# How to get a directive's original content when using a template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/1/edit)</kbd>

Given a directive with a template, how could I get its original content?

For example:

HTML:

```
<div my-directive>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div>Template</div>',
    compile: function(element) {
      console.log(element.html()); // Outputs <div>Template</div>
      // How do I get <input type="text"> ?
    }
  };
});
```

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Get the value of input and put in in div?

Comment: I would like to print out the original contents of the directive. The real example is a bit more complicated that this, so I tried to come up with a minimal example.

Comment: But ultimately you want them to be replaced right? In your real case does it hold a whole lot of stuffs? Do you want to do anything with that content?

Comment: Like this you mean? http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/2/edit

Comment: @PSL In the real example, I need the original HTML in order to present it to the user (need to escape it though). In your jsbin, the output contains `class="ng-scope"` which is automatically added by Angular. I need the original HTML, without all Angular stuff.

Comment: and this? http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/4/edit

Comment: @PSL This is much better :) Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Not yet. Is you directive used only once at a time? Do you load jquery as well?

Comment: I can have multiple directives, and no jQuery please :)

Comment: Alright last example is without jquery, rest of them neede jquery only for getting `index`. let me know if it works and those ones support multiple ofcourse, check out example

Comment: I have removed my answer.. If you want this is it.. http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/11/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just need it for display purpose and not to really use it with bindings and other stuffs and you need it before angular has touched it. You can make use of function expression syntax of `template` property of directive.

Example:-

```
  var content;
  template: function(elm){
      content = elm.html(); //save the html
      return '<div>Template</div>';
   },
```

Extended Example for supporting multiple:-

```
.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  var content={};
  var loadedDirs;
  return {
    scope:true,
    template: function(elm){
      loadedDirs = loadedDirs || 
                   angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('[my-directive]'));
       //Save the element in its respective index    
      content[loadedDirs.index(elm)] = elm.html();

      return '<div>Template<div><pre>{{orig}}</pre></div></div>'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var idx = loadedDirs.index(element);
       scope.orig = content[idx];

       //Remove key
       delete content[idx];
       //Remove reference to loadedDirs
       if(!Object.keys(content)){ 
         loadedDirs = null;
        }  
      }
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/10/edit)**

No Jquery solution (work around for `index`)

```
.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  var content={},
      idx = 0;

  return {
    scope:true,
    template: function(elm){
      elm.idx = idx; //set an iterative index
       //Save the element in its respective index    
      content[idx++] = elm.html(); //save element html in a map

      return '<div>Template<div><pre>{{orig}}</pre></div></div>'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var idx = element.idx; //Get idx property value from the element
       scope.orig = content[idx]; //get the content
      delete content[idx]; //remove the key
      if(!Object.keys(content)){ idx = 0; } //reset idx once all are loaded
     }
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/yezayepepaso/11/edit)**

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there a way to get the original HTML when using transclusion with a template? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26270923/247243)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-transclude, [docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude). You will get the original content appended to the directive template content.

Answer (score 0):

Check this (you do have to set transclude to true, though)

```
angular.module('App', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div>template</div>',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone){
       var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i<clone.length;i++){
          html +=  clone[i].outerHTML || '';
        }
        console.log(html);
      })

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: The output is `<input type="text" class="ng-scope">`, while I need `<input type="text">`.