# AngularJS: How to get the original directive HTML in the "template" function when using transclusion?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/boziwezowuge/1/edit)</kbd>

To get the original HTML of the directive in the `template` function one could do:

HTML:

```
<div my-directive>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: function(element) {
      console.log(element.html()); // Outputs <input type="text">
      return '<div>Template</div>';
    }
  };
});
```

But, when the directive has `transclude: true`, this method doesn't work anymore:

```
angular.module('App', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: function(element) {
      console.log(element.html()); // Outputs empty string
      return '<div>Template</div>';
    }
  };
});
```

Is there a way to get the original HTML **in the `template` function** when using transclusion?

The ultimate goal is to present the original HTML to the user:

```
angular.module('App', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: function(element) {
      var originalHTML = "How do I get it?";

      return '<div>' +
             '  <pre>' +
                  escapeHtml(originalHTML) + // This is the original HTML
             '  </pre>' +
             '  <div ng-transclude></div>' + // and this is how it looks like
             '</div>';
    }
  };
});
```

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/boziwezowuge/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: What's your ultimate aim here? Maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: @MichalCharemza I would like to present the original HTML to the user. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way i could think of is to use  another directive which will save the content to a service accessibly by an identifier. So it mean you would need to add another directive which does this purpose. The directive which does the capture must have higher **priority** that any other directive that uses it.

Example:-

```
.directive('myDirective', function(origContentService) {
  return {

    priority:100,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>Template</div>',
    link:function(scope, elm){
         //get prop and get content
      console.log(origContentService.getContent(elm.idx));
    }
  };
}).directive('capture', function(origContentService){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    priority:200, //<-- This must be higher
    compile:function(elm){
      //Save id and set prop
     elm.idx =  origContentService.setContent(elm.html());
     }
  }
}).service('origContentService', function(){
  var contents = {};
  var idx = 0;
  this.getContent= function(idx){
    return contents[idx];
  }
  this.setContent = function(content){
    contents[++idx] = content;
    return idx;
  }
  this.cleanup = function(){
    contents = null;
  }
});
```

and use `capture` directive along with this:-

```
   <div  my-directive capture>
     <input type="text">
   </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/boziwezowuge/20/edit)**

Or just save the content as data (or a property) itself on the element. so that when the element gets destroyed so will its property.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {

    priority:100,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>Template</div>',
    link:function(scope, elm){

      console.log(elm.data('origContent'));
    }
  };
}).directive('capture', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    priority:200,
    compile:function(elm){

     elm.data('origContent', elm.html());
     }
  }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/boziwezowuge/29/edit)**

Comment: Yeah, two directives would work, but I wonder if it's possible to achieve the same with a single directive. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26289210/247243).

Comment: @MishaMoroshko I dint want to pollute the other answer. Here it is http://jsbin.com/danoqatofaju/15/edit This supports more than 1 directives on the same parent scope and probably more concise and does not have more than one button. If you think this is better i can post this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your efforts!! I think it is much better. Please post this.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko You are welcome. I have posted, take a look. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define where in your template the original HTML code should be inserted.

For Example:

```
angular.module('App', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
          template: '<div>Template</div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>';
    }
 });
```

This will place original HTML after `<div>Template</div>`