# AngularJS: How to implement a directive that outputs its markup?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/danoqatofaju/1/edit)</kbd>

Imagine I have some markup, e.g.:

```
<my-input model="data.firstName"></my-input>
```

Now, I would like to create a `my-markup` directive that will add a button to show/hide its markup.

So, this:

```
<div my-markup>
  <my-input model="data.firstName"></my-input>
</div>
```

should result in this:

[image]

and when the button is clicked, the markup should appear:

[image]

The `my-markup` directive should not break any data bindings of its children.

[Here is my attempt to implement this.](http://jsbin.com/danoqatofaju/1/edit)

The markup appears, but the button doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix this?

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/danoqatofaju/1/edit)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach.  Couple of things:-

1) Instead of isolated scope on myMarkup, create a child scope, ultimately the actual directive `myInput` will be isolated. This would be required if you do need to support multiple `myMarkup` directive under the same scope.

2) You need a click event on the button, i wouldn't do logic on the markup instead abstract out to a method on the scope.

3) You would just need one button, do not need 2 buttons. Just change the text of the button.

```
.directive('myMarkup', function($compile) {


  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true, //Create a child scope
    compile: function(element) {
      //Just need one button
      var showButton = '<button  ng-click="toggleMarkup()">{{model.showMarkup ? "Hide": "Show"}} Markup</button>';
      var markup = '<pre ng-show="model.showMarkup">' + escapeHtml(element.html()) + '</pre>';

      //append the markups
      element.append(showButton).append(markup);

      return linker;
     }
   };

    function linker(scope, element) {
        scope.model = {
          showMarkup: false
        };
        //Click event handler on the button to toggle markup
        scope.toggleMarkup = function(){
          scope.model.showMarkup = !scope.model.showMarkup;
        }
    };
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/danoqatofaju/18/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

Please see below

```js
function escapeHtml(html) {
  return html.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

angular.module('App', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    firstName: 'David'
  };
}).directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    template: '<input class="my-input" type="text" ng-model="model">'
  };
}).directive('myMarkup', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

    },
    compile: function(element) {
      var showButton = '<button ng-if="data.showMarkup" ng-click="data.showMarkup=!data.showMarkup">Hide Markup</button>';
      var hideButton = '<button ng-if="!data.showMarkup" ng-click="data.showMarkup=!data.showMarkup">Show Markup</button>';
      var markup = '<pre ng-if="data.showMarkup">' + escapeHtml(element.html()) + '</pre>';

      element.append(showButton);
      element.append(hideButton);
      element.append(markup);

      return function(scope, element) {
        scope.data = {
          showMarkup: true
        };
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <pre>data = {{ data | json }}</pre>
  <div my-markup>
    <my-input model="data.firstName"></my-input>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! When you click the button, `"showMarkup": true` is set on controller's `data`. Any idea how to prevent this from happening? It should write to directive's `data` instead.